# Cocoa Windows, not receiving events

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

For the last few days I've returned to an issue that I've been having for a while now. I've been trying to integrate Cocoa windows into my application, but the [NSApplication run] doesn't fit in with my programs model and getting the user inputs is more difficult than expected, As no event is received by the window.

I checked with XCode the value of _currentEvent and it's consistently nil which leads me to think that the window isn't capturing the events in the first place. I included a screenshot of the window while it's focused, although it doesn't appear to be active as the icons aren't coloured. I've also included the code for the window creation in Objective-C

Note: Calling [application run] does work and I receive inputs with an active looking window once called.

Update: I overloaded the run function and tried to duplicate what I found in the assembly and I got a working function which handles inputs. The only problem is that I can only call the function inside the CreateCocoaWindow, if I call the function in CocoaWindowUpdate even though they're the same function. Because It's in the CreateCocoaWindow function I can't call it again. I'm currently thinking it's something to do with Objective-C Memory management, which I have little to no experience with.

Source: https://gist.github.com/Joshhua5/4c3a37a683d1cd107a18

Variables:

[image: Variables]

Window:

[image: Window]

Comment: I get nothing at your gist link.

Comment: Sorry, updated the link

Comment: Why would you expect `_currentEvent` to be set? For example, that might be something that `-[NSApplication run]` sets after it gets an event off the queue. Since you're not calling that method, you have to expect that some of the stuff that `NSApplication` normally does will not be done. I recommend that you try to use a more traditional architecture for your app. If necessary, dedicate the main thread to Cocoa and move your other code to a secondary thread. (I have some experience with this.)

Comment: I would of already tried that, it occurred to me. But the program is cross platform and I don't have control over how the user implements their main loop.

Do you know of a place I can see a working implementation of the run function?

Comment: Just a point of interests regard my update, in the source code on line 60 I allocate and then line 79 I make my reference, is it possible that this reference isn't counted?

Comment: There's an implementation in Apple's deprecated [GLUT sample project](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/glut/Listings/GLUTApplication_m.html). I'm not sure what you're asking about lines 60 and 79. "Isn't counted" for what? ARC?

Comment: I'm sorry for such a bad question, the problem is visible though but only just. In the debugger picture if you look at the callback details you can see that function call is in Thread 12. My problem with my own version of run was that I wasn't calling it from the main thread, The window is operational now. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that my implementation of the run function wasn't being called from the main thread.